# Is this possible to count index posistion of my current node that belonging to the child of <w:body> using xslt2.0?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

This is my Xml Document.

```
<w:document xmlns:w="w">
<w:body>
   <w:p>
        <w:r>
           <w:t>
               Para1
            </w:t>
        </w:r>
     </w:p>
   <w:p>
        <w:r>
           <w:t>
               Para2
            </w:t>
        </w:r>
     </w:p>
   <w:p>
        <w:r>
           <w:t>
               Para3
            </w:t>
        </w:r>
     </w:p>
   <w:p>
        <w:r>
           <w:t>
               Para4
            </w:t>
        </w:r>
     </w:p>
   <w:p>
        <w:r>
           <w:t>
               Para5
            </w:t>
        </w:r>
     </w:p>

   <w:tbl>
         <w:tr>
            <w:tc>
               <w:p>
                  <w:r>
                    <w:t>
                         Para6
                    </w:t>
                   </w:r>
                </w:p>
              </w:tc>
            <w:tc>
               <w:p>
                  <w:r>
                    <w:t>
                         Para7 <!-- Just Assume, this is current Node -->
                    </w:t>
                   </w:r>
                </w:p>
              </w:tc>
           </w:tr>
        </w:tbl>
     <w:p>
        <w:r>
           <w:t>
               Para8
            </w:t>
        </w:r>
     </w:p>

</w:body>
</w:document>
```

So, now i want to get the index position of current node that belonging to the child of `<w:body>`.So My expected output is :6.

for example,

1. if current node is para6 then my output is also 6.
2. if current node is para8 then my output is 7.
3. if current node is para5 then my output is 5.

If possible, Please Guide me to get this...

**New Update:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                              xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main"
                              xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml"
                              xmlns:pic="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/picture"
                              xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
                              xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
                              extension-element-prefixes="exsl">


  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="*">
      <Document>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="//w:p">
         </xsl:apply-templates>
      </Document>
    </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="w:p">

       <xsl:variable name="index">
            <xsl:call-template name="get-para-index">
                 <xsl:with-param name="node" select="."/>
            </xsl:call-template>
       </xsl:variable>

     <Paragraph>
            <xsl:attribute name="index">
                 <xsl:value-of select="$index" />
            </xsl:attribute>

            <xsl:apply-templates select="./w:r/w:t"/>
     </Paragraph>

  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="w:t">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="get-para-index">
       <xsl:param name="node"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="count($node/ancestor::*[parent::w:body]/preceding-sibling::*)+1"/>     <!-- Need to write logic here -->
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I just calling the `get-para-index template` for get the index position of each and every `<w:p>`.But it returns always 1 for every `<w:p>`. Please Guide me to get out of this problem...

Thanks & Regards,
P.SARAVANAN

Comment: Your input XML is not valid. There appears to be a rogue **w:p** element near the end. Can you give it a quick tidy-up, please, to avoid any confusion? Thanks!

Comment: @_Tim: I am very very sorry for this.I will definitely put valid content further.Please refer my question now...

Comment: @Tim : did u check my updated question?...Anyone Please help me to get this problem

Comment: Forty-two's answer looks correct to me. That's the answer I was going to give before he got in there first!

Comment: @Tim:for example, I have passed my current node as a parameter named node.then, i want to count the ancestor of this $node whose parent is <w:body> and then take preceding-sibling of that ancestor +1.But his did not work at all.

Comment: There is currently nothing in the question about passing in the current node as a parameter. If you amend your question to mention about this, then I am sure forty-two will be able to amend his XSLT to include this.

Comment: 2_Tim: Ok i will update my question now with my xslt file

Comment: Please See my Updated question with xlst file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure of what you want but this expression

```
count(ancestor::*[parent::w:body]/preceding-sibling::*)+1
```

from the context node, finds the ancestor whose parent is <w:body>, then selects all preceding sibling elements and counts those. Adding 1 should give you the position.

Comment: I think you need to use **ancestor-or-self** and not **ancestor** here, because otherwise it won't work in the case where the current node is a **w:p** tag that is an immediate child of the **w:body** tag.

Comment: @TimC:Thank you very much for your support.I found one way of doing this.But i dont know whether it is best one or not?. Please tell your opinion abt my solution.I will put my answer now...

Answer (score 0):

My Updated Xslt that fulfilled my requests...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                              xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main"
                              xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml"
                              xmlns:pic="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/picture"
                              xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
                              xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
                              extension-element-prefixes="exsl">


  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="*">
      <Document>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="//w:p">
         </xsl:apply-templates>
      </Document>
    </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="w:p">

       <xsl:variable name="index">
            <xsl:call-template name="get-para-index">
                 <xsl:with-param name="node" select="."/>
            </xsl:call-template>
       </xsl:variable>

     <Paragraph>
            <xsl:attribute name="index">
                 <xsl:value-of select="$index" />
            </xsl:attribute>

            <xsl:apply-templates select="./w:r/w:t"/>
     </Paragraph>

  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="w:t">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="get-para-index">
       <xsl:param name="node"/>

    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="$node/ancestor::*[parent::w:body]">
        <xsl:value-of select="count($node/ancestor::*[parent::w:body]/preceding-sibling::*)"/>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="count($node/preceding-sibling::*)"/>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>          
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```